# python-libtorrent torrent_info method

Tags: python, python-2.x, torrent, libtorrent

I've been using `python-libtorrent` to check what pieces belong to a file in a torrent containing multiple files.

I'm using the below code to iterate over the torrent file

```
info = libtorrent.torrent_info('~/.torrent')
for f in info.files():
    print f
```

But this returns `<libtorrent.file_entry object at 0x7f0eda4fdcf0>` and I don't know how to extract information from this.

I'm unaware of the `torrent_info` property which would return piece value information of various files. Some help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

the API is documented [here](https://libtorrent.org/reference-Torrent_Info.html#torrent_info) and [here](https://libtorrent.org/reference-Storage.html#file_storage). Obviously the python API can't always be exactly as the C++ one. But generally the interface takes a file index and returns some property of that file.

Answer (score 0):

```
info = libtorrent.torrent_info('~/.torrent')
for f in info.files():
    # print f  
    print (f.path)
```

You will get the important message...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).